# C++ _getch() read multiple values

Tags: c++

```
#define KEY_UP 72
#define KEY_DOWN 80
#define KEY_LEFT 75
#define KEY_RIGHT 77

int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    while (c != 27)    //esc key code
    {
        c = 0;

        switch (c = _getch()) 
        {
        case KEY_UP:
            cout << endl << "Up" << endl;//key up
            break;
        case KEY_DOWN:
            cout << endl << "Down" << endl;   // key down
            break;
        case KEY_LEFT:
            cout << endl << "Left" << endl;  // key left
            break;
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            cout << endl << "Right" << endl;  // key right
            break;
        default:
            cout << endl << "null" << endl;
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be

```
Up
Down
Left
Right
```

But what I get is

```
null
Up
null
Down
null
Left
null
Right
```

Based on the output, the program will read in other key code which I have no idea what is that before reading the actual key code, I didn't have any `cin` before this, why? any solution?

Comment: Those are probably `\n`.

Comment: And which law exactly prevented you from printing the value of the read key, in the `default:` section, in order to determine what else is being read, in order to figure out what's happening?

Comment: `_getch()` is not C++. It appears to be some Microsoft extension.

Comment: I'm also interested in discovering what prevented you from simply reading the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had you chosen to [read the fine manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx), you would have encountered this statement:

> When reading a function key or an arrow key, each function must be called twice; the first call returns 0 or `0xE0`, and the second call returns the actual key code.

That's how you can tell when 72 means arrow-up and when it's the letter `H` (which happens to have an ASCII code of 72).

Comment: So it reads it as H or arrow? and what will be the actual implementation?

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Changes made:

I removed `default` from the switch statement. It was causing the null prints.

Furthermore I've also added `kbhit()` and  `#define KEY_ESC 27`, and moved `getch()` to ouside of the switch statement.

```
#define KEY_UP 72
#define KEY_DOWN 80
#define KEY_LEFT 75
#define KEY_RIGHT 77
#define KEY_ESC 27

#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>     
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int c = 0;

    while ( c!= KEY_ESC )    //esc key code is 27
    {
        if (kbhit()) {
            c = getch();

                switch ( c ) 
                {
                case KEY_UP:
                    cout << endl << "Up" << endl;//key up
                    break;
                case KEY_DOWN:
                    cout << endl << "Down" << endl;   // key down
                    break;
                case KEY_LEFT:
                    cout << endl << "Left" << endl;  // key left
                    break;
                case KEY_RIGHT:
                    cout << endl << "Right" << endl;  // key right
                    break;

                }//switch

        }//if

    }//while

    return 0;
}
```